# Concatenar 2 variáveis PHP em instrução SQL

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema PHP com Oracle e para "otimizar" um update, precisaria concatenar uma variável (com valores de 1 a 3) no nome da variável que irei passar na instrução. As variáveis vem de um formulário, e preciso passar uma por uma, sem usar array.

Segue abaixo um trecho que está hoje:

```
$update .="CODIGO = '$produto_1' AND ";
```

O exemplo acima, precisaria passar algo assim, onde o `$passo` teria valores fixos (hoje de 1 a 3):

```
$update .="CODIGO = '$produto_.$passo' AND ";
```

Nesse caso deveria passar como váriavel também `$produto_1`, depois `$produto_2`......

Usando o ponto para concatenar não funcionou. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso fica muito complexo, use *arrays*, por este motivo eles existem, pois se não você terá que usar `eval`, que seria algo como (recomendo que **não use** `eval`, é apenas para exemplificar):

```
$var1 = eval('return $produto_' . $passo);

$update .="CODIGO = '$var1' AND ";
```

Então faça com `array`, que seria algo como:

```
$produto = array();

$produto[1] = ...;
$produto[2] = ...;

$update .= "CODIGO = '" . $produto[$passo] . "' AND ";
```

Você citou formulário, então posso presumir que se refere ao HTML, você pode fazer assim também:

```
<form method="POST" action="pagina.php">
    <input type="text" name="passo[]" value="a">
    <input type="text" name="passo[]" value="b">
    <input type="text" name="passo[]" value="c">
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

E no PHP irá obter assim:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST['passo']);
```

A saída será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, usando o eval resolveu o problema. Obrigado.

Comment: @Diego talvez seja melhor usar o array como citei, ou então a resposta do http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151986/3635, que para você seria algo como `${"produto_{$passo}"}`

Comment: Vou fazer mais alguns testes, se ficar muito ruim vou passar para array. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Diego eu corrigi o exemplo, na verdade eu queria dizer assim `$update .= "CODIGO = '" . $produto[$passo] . "' AND ";`, acho que fica mais facil :)

Comment: Quando uma solução leva a um `eval`, é hora de pensar em refatorar tudo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mas eu disse para não usar e o que o certo é mudar para array (ou está querendo dizer isto para o Diego?)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tá tudo certo. Então, você mostrou a refatoração na sua resposta (a opção dos arrays). Além de ter ficado mais organizado, evita problemas de legiblidade e de segurança. Na verdade, eu não podia perder a piada :D

Answer (score 4):

Eu usei o extract para gerar o teste das variáveis `passo_X`, mas a logica aplicada seria a do `for`.

```
$arrayPassos = array(
    'passo_1' => 'teste1',
    'passo_2' => 'teste2',
    'passo_3' => 'teste3',
    'passo_4' => 'teste4',
);
extract($arrayPassos); // criada variaves passo_X

$out = '';
for ($i=1; $i <= count($arrayPassos); $i++){
    $out .= ${"passo_{$i}"};
}
```

#### Nota

- para esses caso é melhor utilizar `array`, e não variáveis numeradas.

Comment: Nossa é verdade, raramente usei isso, mas funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento da pra usar para chamadas de funções também :D

Comment: É praticamente o `eval` então :/

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não exatamente, seria quase um `$$nameVar`

Answer (score 2):

> Usando o ponto para concatenar não funcionou. Alguma sugestão?

Não funcionou como o esperado porque a tentativa de concatenação está sendo feita entre aspas, o `.` está sendo interpretado como um caractere qualquer, e não como [operador de concatenação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php).

Segue outra alternativa:

```
$update .= "CODIGO = '{$produto}_{$passo}' AND ";
```

**Edição**: Também é possível [referenciar](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) a variável num loop:

```
$produto_1 = "PROD1";
$produto_2 = "PROD2";
$produto_3 = "PROD3";

$limite = 3;
$update = "";

for ($passo = 1; $passo <= $limite; $passo++) {
    $update .= "CODIGO = '" . ${"produto_$passo"} . "' AND ";
}

echo $update;
// CODIGO = 'PROD1' AND CODIGO = 'PROD2' AND CODIGO = 'PROD3' AND
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/G98Hdz)</kbd>

Comment: Na verdade ele quer gerar a variavel $produto_1, $produto_2. E não as variaveis $produto e $passo, veja: http://ideone.com/pYZfTJ, isso vai gerar algo como 1_2, mas o que ele quer é que `$produto . '_' . $passo` vire isto `$produto_1` e que obtenha o valor de `$produto_1 = 1;` por exemplo. Como citei, o melhor caminho são os arrays :)

Comment: Nesse seu exemplo, ele reconhece como variável o $produto, e não o $produto_1, já que o 1 é o valor que está armazenado no $passo....

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas acho que ele tem um loop que itera com o `$passo`

Comment: @stderr a sim, foi um erro de digitação, obrigado :) ... sim acho que é isto mesmo que o AP precisava, do seu exemplo do ideone.

Answer (score 1):

Pode montar a concatenação com a função `sprintf()` também, os `%s` são trocados pelas repectivas variáveis (valores) na ordem que aparecem.

```
$passo = $_POST['passo']; 
$update .= sprinf("CODIGO = '%s_%s'", $produto, $passo);
```